# Postgres Replication From Different Masters?

Tags: postgresql, replication, recovery

I'm getting a Postgres 9.3.3 install sorted out. My application is Drupal (so read/write), but low-traffic, so all application traffic is sent to the primary master. I have two sites (main and secondary) with two machines in each (again, main and secondary). let's say machines 1 and 2 are in the main site, with machines 3 and 4 in the secondary site.

Right now, 1 is the master, and 2,3 and 4 are all hot_standby slaves of it (the master has a DNS CNAME, which is in the recovery.conf files). I've been told that if I wanted to flip between sites, I'd need to promote 3 as the master (by touching the /tmp file), and then can update the DNS to point to machine 3 instead of machine 1. I can then restart each of the slaves and they'll magically start replicating from 3 instead of 1.

This sort of strategy absolutely won't work with MySQL, but can it work with Postgres? If needs be, I can stop Drupal from accessing the database while I do this sort of work, to avoid any writes being made. Could it work then?

Is there another strategy I should be using to make changing sites (or machines in a site) relatively easy? Could cascading replication from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 maybe make more sense? I could then promote 3 (and have 4 as a slave of it), but then have to rebuild 1 and 2 to become slaves of 4.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but my understanding is that the new "timelines" introduced in 9.3 are specifically made for this use case: a slave following a new master without the need to completely re-initialize the slave from scratch - which would be necessary in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - yes, timelines appear to do what I need here. I may do cascading replication as well though.